# Meaning of equation about maximization of the correspondence score between two collections

Tags: matrices, algorithms, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to interpret the following:

> $x$ is an indicator vector such that $x(a) = 1$ if candidate
>   assignment a represents a corresponding pair of nodes and $0$
>   otherwise. We aim to find an optimal solution $x^*$ which maximizes
>   the score
>
> $x^*=argmax (x^TMx)$
>
> The solution to the above problem, $x^*$, gives the optimal
>   correspondence between feature points in $P$ and $Q$

Note: matrix $M$ consists of both $P$ and $Q$ assigned to cells according to some rules

Heatmap of $M$ example:[image], where light means that $P$ is similar to $Q$ and dark represents dissimilarity. (aka affinity matrix)

---

My question is:

- Does $x^*$ from the quote simply means a principal eigenvector of $M$?

I would say **yes** based on 2 quotes from different papers:

> We interpret x*(a) as the association of a with the best cluster C*.
>   Since only the relative values between the elements of x matter, we
>   can fix the norm of x to 1. Then, by the Raleigh’s ratio theorem, x*
>   that will maximize the inter-cluster score x^(T)Mx is the principal
>   eigenvector of M

and

> x* can be found by inspecting the eigenvector of M corresponding to
>   its largest eigenvalue

Comment: As it is written in the question, $x^*$ is **the optimal solution which maximizes the score $x^TMx$**. $M$ may not even have eigenvectors, so no, $x^*$ is not the eigenvector in general.

Comment: @5xum quote from another paper: `We interpret x*(a) as the association of a with the best cluster C*. Since only the relative values between the elements of x matter, we can fix the norm of x to 1. Then, by the Raleigh’s ratio theorem, x* that will maximize the inter-cluster score x^(T)Mx is the principal eigenvector of M`

Comment: Well, is the matrix symmetrc?

Comment: @5xum yes, it is

Comment: Then the answer is completely different, because symmetric matrices are diagonalizable. Still, what you quoted is sloppy, as it does not tell you what to do if $M$ has two principal eigenvectors.

Comment: @5xum i thought the principal eigenvector is the eigenvector associated with the highest (or lowest) eigenvalue

Comment: It is. So what is the principal eigenvector of the identity matrix?

Comment: @5xum ..where every eigenvector would represent a different cluster in M

Comment: Matrices can have double or triple eigenvalues, in which case they have more than one principal eigenvector, and they all optimize the formula you stated.

Comment: @5xum Exactly. Every eigenvector I obtain represents a different cluster, where every cluster represents unique set of P and Q assignments. In further computations I use a number (i.e. 5) of eigenvectors and I use them to decide on differences between 2 different matrices

Comment: You can check Hagen et al. 1992, New spectral methods for ratio cut partition and clustering. It may answer some of your question. Along with Luxburg 2007.

Comment: @davcha thank you, i will